# Express-js no puede conseguir mis archivos estáticos

Tags: nodejs, express

Buenas, tengo problemas para obtener los archivos estáticos en Nodejs con

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Cuando ingreso a la ruta raíz "/"(http://localhost:8080) o "/principal"(http://localhost:8080/principal) funciona sin problemas, carga todo los css, js, imágenes etc. Pero cuando ingreso a una ruta como "/principal/secundaria" (http://localhost:8080/principal/secundaria) no encuentra los archivos. Veo en la consola del navegador los errores y me sale algo como:

```
(X)GET "http://localhost:8080/principal/css/home.css"
```

No sé como arreglar esto. Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Olvídenlo, ya lo resolví. El error era en la ruta que estaba colocando en el Head del html:

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
```

Y tiene que ser así:

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="/css/home.css">
```

De esa manera me toma el estilo home.css para todas las rutas.